# Taking just one Header Column during converting 3 txt files into one txt file with PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, concatenation

Suppose that I have three txt files that include table in below;

| Sales | Purchase |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 6 |

I would like to concatenate these txt files into one  txt file...

I used this code;

```
import pandas
import glob
file_names = glob.glob("./*.txt")
with open('output_file.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    for i in file_names:
        with open(i) as in_file:
            for j in in_file:
                out_file.write(j)
data = pandas.read_csv("output_file.txt", delimiter='/')
```

However the result is like that:

| Sales | Purchase |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 6 |
| Sales | Purchase |
| 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 6 |
| Sales | Purchase |
| 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 6 |

I would like to take just one "Sales and Purchase" row and would like to drop the other Sales and Purchase rows.

How can I drop these rows. By the way that maybe txt files number can increase...

My expected result is like that:

| Sales | Purchase |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 6 |
| 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 6 |

Answer (score 0):

If all your .txt files have the same structure, you can add a condition in your second loop so that for every file but the first one, you skip the first row:

```
import pandas
import glob
file_names = glob.glob("./*.txt")
with open('output_file.txt', 'w') as out_file:
    for index, i in enumerate(file_names):
        if index == 0:  # First file
            with open(i) as in_file:
                for j in in_file:
                    out_file.write(j)
        else:  # The rest of the files
            with open(i) as in_file:
                for j in in_file:
                    if 'Sales' in j:
                        continue  # Skip the row containing 'Sales'
                    else:
                        out_file.write(j)
data = pandas.read_csv("output_file.txt", delimiter='/')
```

Comment: Yes. You could also simply skip the first line with `next` and use only one loop (`with open(i) as in_file: if index == 0: _ = next(in_file) for j in...`)

Comment: Thank you but  I'am getting a NameError: name 'i' is not defined

Comment: My bad, I forgot to change one of the variable names in the loop when adapting your code. I edited my answer to fix this.

Comment: Thank you very much. It seems that welll working

Answer (score 0):

If you read each input file as a CSV (which seems to be implied by the question notwithstanding the .txt file extension) then you just need to create a dataframe from each input file then concatenate them to produce the output file as follows:

```
from glob import glob
import os
import pandas

SRC_DIR = '/Volumes/G-Drive/Data'
OUTPUT_FILE = '/Volumes/G-Drive/output.txt'
DELIMITER = '/'

dflist = []

for file in glob(os.path.join(SRC_DIR, '*.txt')):
    dflist.append(pandas.read_csv(file, delimiter=DELIMITER))

df = pandas.concat(dflist, ignore_index=True)

df.to_csv(OUTPUT_FILE, sep=DELIMITER, index=False)
```

If you don't want to use *pandas* then it's as simple as:

```
with open(OUTPUT_FILE, 'w') as output:
    for file in glob(os.path.join(SRC_DIR, '*.txt')):
        with open(file) as data:
            header = next(data)
            if output.tell() == 0:
                output.write(header)
            for row in data:
                output.write(row)
```